# Convert full format date to year month format in Python

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe have one column `date` which has the following data:

```
0         2019/5/20 22:49:29
1         2019/5/20 23:18:23
2           2019/3/8 9:11:35
3           2019/3/8 9:19:58
4         2019/5/20 22:57:12
5           2019/3/8 9:06:41
```

How can I convert it to format `year-month`:

```
0         2019-05
1         2019-05
2         2019-03
3         2019-03
4         2019-05
5         2019-03
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('M')
```